# Ignoring Java mouse events on AWT components that were generated from lightweight components

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent

I have a JFileChooser that is opened on top of an AWT component (we use a GLCanvas for some openGL rendering). If I double click the icon in the file chooser to close it, the mouse clicks are passed to the GLCanvas. I have read that mouse events on the lightweight components will be passed to the heavyweight components, but is there a way to detect when this is happening? Double clicking on the GLCanvas performs another operation, which I would prefer not happen when the user is just double clicking to close the dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create event handlers for the mouse events on the lightweight components and then do nothing inside of them, that should stop the propagation to the heavier components.

Something like:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
```

Comment: +1, I was thinking the same, but I wasn't too sure. Also, you could just simply register a `MouseAdapter` in the following way - `addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){})`. This will effectively do the same thing, without the verbosity.

Comment: That way is probably better, it is more concise atleast. This was the first thing that came into my head.

Comment: @mre, yes, I just added a new MouseAdapter, but conceptually still the same.